# What are function pointers good for in Go if you can't assign them values?

Tags: go, function-pointers

Can you do anything in Go with a `*func()`?

```golang
    var f func() = foo // works
    var g *func() // works
    g = foo // fails `cannot use foo (type func()) as type *func() in assignment` as expected
    g = &foo // fails too `cannot take the address of foo`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take the address of a function definition, you can take the address of a function *value*. This works:

```
g := &f
```

Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/BokYCrVmV_p

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it around and set it:

```
func a(f *func()) {
  *f = foo
}

func main() {
   var f func()

   a(&f)
   f()
}
```